# mysql sort string as date not as string

Tags: mysql, sorting, date

The DB I inherited stored there dates like:  yyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss

I was hoping to sort by date in my mysql query but it is treating them like a string and sorting accordingly.

Any one know of a way to sort them as a date and not a string in the query itself?

Thanks,
Robert

Comment: Wouldn't the string be sorted correctly as it is saved as yyyy-mm-dd? I'm assuming the 3 y is a typo mistake in your post.

Comment: Does it really matter if it treats them as strings? As far as I can tell the outcome should be the same and if you're worried about performance you could just add an index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try casting the value to a date and sorting by that:

```
ORDER BY CAST(SDate As DATETIME);
```