# Sorting a list based on multiple fields and each fields can be in different directions

Tags: java, spring, sorting, jpa, guava

Looking for Sorting a List of class Employee

```
class Employee {

String name;
int age;
String dob;    
}
```

I am looking to sort the list like if the name is equal then age if age is also equal then check dob.
All these can be in different directions. For example

the name can be ascending order, age can be descending order.

The URL that I am using in my Rest Controller has

```
orderBy=name,desc&orderBy=age,asc&&orderBy=dob,asc
```

I was looking for Spring Data JPA using Pageable.

But the problem is the Date of Birth in Database is in String.

So I need to convert that to Date.

Then next Option I thought about Ordering in Guava.

```
Ordering<Employee> orderPrimary = Ordering.natural().onResultOf(new EmployeeOrderByName());

Ordering<Employee> orderSecondary = Ordering.natural().reverse().onResultOf(new EmployeeOrderByAge()); 
orderPrimary.compound(orderSecondary);
```

But in Url fields can be in a different order and can be in a different direction, here I am not sure how to proceed.

Any best approach to meet my requirement.

Comment: What you mean by "But in Url fields can be in a different order"? Your rest controller should take `Pageable` which will have fields in a `List`. Whatever order they are in the List should be the order you need to compare by.

Comment: @tsolakp Like I mentioned in using pageable, the problem is that Date Of Birth in the database is in String, So I have to convert that to Date. Not sure how pageable will work in that case. "But in Url fields can be in a different order" - Yes I will be using the order in the list

Comment: The problem with in memory ordering is that you need to do sorting in database to get proper paged data. Otherwise you have to load all the data and then do in memory paging and sorting which can get very expensive.

Comment: What database are you using, postgres or mysql or other? Depending on rdbms and its version, you can convert String to date by SQL converting function and you can order from this.

Comment: @Aroniaina MySQL , can you elaborate a bit more

Comment: You can see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4629482/mysql-sort-string-as-date-not-as-string
or this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17093417/mysql-order-by-varchar-date-in-mmm-dd-yyyy

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a `@Converter` to convert to dob string to/from Date and then use order by in criteria or query .... but you need to make some trial and error because converters don't work very well with queries (and most probably with Criteria also) ... [here is a tutorial on Converter](https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/jpa-21-how-to-implement-type-converter/)